# Automatically open the browser after losing the connection to a specific IP (Batch File)

Tags: batch-file, ip

Actually I am very new to batch and this forum, so this is my first question here.

My goal is to create a batch-program which keeps checking if a specific IP is reachable.
As soon as it stops to be reachable / loses connection, it should open a browser and a specific website on it.

Could maybe someone help me with it? Here is, what i created so far, but it does not work very well:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

@echo off

set ipaddr=127.0.0.1

:loop

set state=down

for /f "tokens=8,10" %%a in ('ping -n 1 !ipaddr!') do (
    if "x%%a"=="xLost" if "x%%b"=="x1," set state=up
    (cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\"
    start firefox.exe http://www.google.com
    )

)

echo.Link is !state!

ping -n 6 127.0.0.1 >nul: 2>nul:

endlocal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unsure, what "does not work very well" means. But I suggest another way, that works independend of locale Settings and uses the default browser:

```
set ipaddr=www.stackoverflow.com
:Loop
ping -n 6 127.0.0.1 >nul: 2>nul:
ping -n 1 %ipaddr%|find "(0%" >nul && goto Loop
echo Connection lost
REM start the site in the Default browser:
start "" http://www.google.com
```